# how to replace a document for its _id when there are dynamic

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a sample document:

```
#Data model:
{
    "name": "tub",
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "record_id": "6298ab81829d286ebb4015b9"
        },
        "2": {
            "record_id": "6298ab81829d286ebb4015b9"
        },
        "3": {
            "record_id": "6298ab81829d286ebb4015b9"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
await DataModel.aggregate().match({name: "tub"}).lookup({
    from: "records",
    localfield: "<somesortofselector>",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "record"
})
```

so, that all the record_id would be replaced with the actual documents,
giving me something like this:

```
{
    "name": "tub",
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "record": {
                _id: "6298ab81829d286ebb4015b9",
                key: "first record"
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "record": {
                _id: "6298ab81829d286ebb4015b9",
                key: "second record"
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "record": {
                _id: "6298ab81829d286ebb4015b9",
                key: "third record"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if that's the right way to do it, but, the end result is what I'm going for

Comment: Why don't you use ```.populate()``` method ?

Comment: Maybe `{$set: {data: { $objectToArray: "$data" }}}`?

Comment: @ZahidÇakıcı , I'm using aggregate, so, my IDE gave me error when I used populate

Comment: @ZahidÇakıcı , also, when I use populate, I can't rename the queried fields

Comment: @ZahidÇakıcı , is there a way to populate all references that exist on a query? (i.e. without giving a path, and no matter how deeply nested)

Comment: @juztcode I don't think I understand your question body.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$objectToArray` as @WernfriedDomscheit suggested, but with `$map`:

1. The `$objectToArray` will set the key as a value of a known key `k`.
2. `$set` an array of the _ids that we want to get their documents.
3. `$lookup` for these documents on the other collection and collect them on `data` array.
4. Take the data from the data array and match it to the original data.
5. format the answer

```
db.allCol.aggregate([
  {$set: {data: {$objectToArray: "$data" }}},
  {$set: {_ids: "$data.v.record_id"}},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "records",
      localField: "_ids",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "records"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          in: {
            k: "$$this.k",
            v: {
              record: {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$records",
                  {$indexOfArray: ["$records._id", "$$this.v.record_id"]}
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      _ids: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  {$set: {data: {$arrayToObject: "$data"}, records: "$$REMOVE"}}
])
```

[MongoDB playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5CQ57KsOayA)

Comment: This works, but, is a bit hard to understand. Is there a syntax that helps us skip a key in `localField: 'stages.<SYNTAX>.record_id'` , that would account for any dynamic key path?

Comment: Not for this case. There is something like this for updating, but only on the same collection. The `$objectToArray` allows you to create a value from the key, and have a known key for it

Comment: The playground link on the original answer allows to look at it step by step